# First Monday of the Year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I find "First Monday of the Year" using T-SQL ?

Comment: The current year, or are you going to specify the year?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually, I am tring to find the logic, let's say it is with parameter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the example from the link ngruson posted (http://sqlbump.blogspot.nl/2010/01/first-monday-of-year.html):

```
DECLARE @Date datetime
DECLARE @Year int = 2012

SET @Date = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900, 0)

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (@@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date) + 
    (8 - @@DATEFIRST) * 2) % 7, @Date)
```

The above returns:

```
2012-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Finally!  One that take DATEFIRST into consideration and actually works.  +1

Answer (score 2):

```
    Here, 
    1) DATEPART function for finding day of week. 
Here 1=sunday,2=monday,..,7=saturday.
    2) first find out is 2(monday) in case when
 condition then get same date,
    3) if is sunday(1) then add 1 day and get next
 day date is for monday,
    4) if is not 2(monday) and greater then 2 then find 
difference between lastday(7) and add 2 days ,
 so we reach to monday date.

    Here are you change year in @year variable. Ex:

        DECLARE @Date datetime
        DECLARE @Year int = 2012

        set @Date= convert(varchar(4),@Year) + '-01-01'
        select @Date,(case when DATEPART(DW,@Date)=2 then @Date
                     when DATEPART(DW,@Date)=1 then DATEADD(day,1,@Date)
                     else DATEADD(day,7-DATEPART(DW,@Date)+2,@Date)
                      end) as MondayDateis
```

Comment: Only the given example works and only if DATEFIRST is set to 7.  Such code really needs to handle all of that automatically because not everyone uses 7 for DATEFIRST.  See the sys.syslanguages table for proof of that.

Answer (score 1):

Elegant it is not ;)

```
    DECLARE @year DATETIME = '01 jan 2012'

    SELECT [Day] 
    FROM
        (
            SELECT @year [Day] UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @year) UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2, @year) UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 3, @year) UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 4, @year) UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 5, @year) UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 6, @year)
        ) x
    WHERE
        DATENAME(DW, [Day]) = 'Monday'
```

Comment: ...and if the language is not English ?

Comment: Then there wouldn't be a first Monday of the year *obviously*

Comment: At least it's NOT sensitive to DATEFIRST settings, like many of the others are.   :P Unfortunately, it only works if the date is in January of the year and there's no time attached to the date.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example to accomplish that:

http://sqlbump.blogspot.nl/2010/01/first-monday-of-year.html

Comment: This is the reason why they don't like links.  The link above is dead and has been replaced with a "Blog has been removed" message.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @yr int=2020
select case when datepart(weekday,dateadd(year,@yr-1900,0))=1 then dateadd(year,@yr-1900,1)
       else dateadd(dd,8-(datepart(weekday,dateadd(year,@yr-1900,0))),dateadd(year,@yr-1900,1))
end
```

#### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6531)

Comment: Hello again. If you run your code for 2013, it says the first Monday is the 8th (which is a Tuesday). Its a small point, I know...

Comment: Hi. I'll try and be more specific. Your suggested code does not work for all values of @@datefirst *(see accepted answer for example)*. If your SQL Server environment has the first day of the week set as a Sunday *(US default)*, you will get your answer. However, if you change the first day of the week to something else, like a Monday, you get a different answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is another one that breaks if DATEFIRST isn't 7.

Answer (score 0):

This approach does not use magic years like 1900 or magic dates.

```
DECLARE @first_year_day     DATE,
        @first_year_monday  DATE,
        @year               int = 2017

SET @first_year_day    = CAST('1/1/' + str(@year, 4) AS DATE)
SET @first_year_monday    = DATEADD(day, (9 - DATEPART(dw, @first_year_day)) % 7, @first_year_day)
SELECT @first_year_monday
```

The code works only if week is configured to start with Sunday in SQL Server preferences. This is by default for most English installations (SELECT @@DATEFIRST will return 7 in this case)

Comment: 1900 - is not a 'magic' year.  It is infact the year off of which most computing systems base their date structure.

Comment: @JamieMarshall It isn't clear from [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) that _most_ computing systems treat 1900 as The Beginning Of Time. Would you be so kind as to provide a citation for this fact?

Comment: @HABO - Great wiki link.  I stand corrected.

Comment: However the epoch date for SQL Server specifically is January 1 1900.  So though I was technically wrong in my wording, I think the solution here is still needlessly complex, as that date will always work.

Comment: @JamieMarshall What defines the epoch for SQL Server? Yes, the base date for SQL Server's [date/time data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes) is 1900-01-01. And 0001-01-01 and 1753-01-01. Then there is the [two digit year cutoff configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) to enhance the fun of importing date strings. ...

Comment: @JamieMarshall ... [`Cast`/`Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) says "When casting character data representing only date or only time components to the `datetime` or `smalldatetime` data types, the unspecified time component is set to 00:00:00.000, and the unspecified date component is set to 1900-01-01." 1900-01-01 was likely chosen since it is the earliest date supported by both data types.

Comment: My definition of an Epoch for SQL Server and a lot of other computation systems is when the underlying date serial number is exactly equal to zero.  For DATETIME, that date is 1900-01-01.  For DATE, DATETIME2, and the variations of those, the underlying date serial number is 0 on 0001-01-01.  Both are, very fortunately, on the same day of the week.  The various versions of the UNIX TimeStamp ALL return a date of 1970-01-01 when the underlying UNIX TimeStamp (which is a Date Serial Number, as well) is equal to 0.  We won't talk about Excel here. :D It thinks 1900-02-29 is a valid date. :P

Answer (score -1):

I needed to group some data by week and display the first day of each week (in my case sunday).  I used the following to calculate the first sunday of a year, you can then use the week number to get the start of the week that a given date happened on.

```
DECLARE @firstSundayThisYear DATE,
    @jan1ThisYear DATE,
    @currentYear INT;

SELECT @jan1ThisYear = '01-jan-' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)),
    @currentYear = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE());

SET @firstSundayThisYear = DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(weekday, @jan1ThisYear) + 1, @jan1ThisYear);

PRINT @firstSundayThisYear
```

NOTE: @firstSundayThisYear may actually be a date from last year but when you multiply by the week number it will all work out.

Comment: But,,. it doesn't.  For a date of 2023-01-29, it returns 2023-01-01, which is a Sunday.  If you change DATEFIRST to anything for that date, it returns a date from 2022.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an 8 year old question but thought I'd throw my hat into the ring anyway

The first snippet below creates a test table to demonstrate that the code that follows that doesn't suffer any RBAR issues.  The solution is actually the fairly short formula that populates the "FirstMondayOfYear" column in the result from the second snippet.  Everything else is just to add to the demonstration.  No separate SETs, no CASE statements, and no references to DATEFIRST are required.

```
--===== Create a test table that contains random dates and times from 1900-01-01 up to and not
     -- including 2100-01-01.
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MyHead
;
 SELECT TOP 100000
        SomeDateTime = RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*DATEDIFF(dd,'1900','2100')+CONVERT(DATETIME,'1900') --Inherently DATETIME
--        SomeDateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME2(7),RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*DATEDIFF(dd,'1900','2100')+CONVERT(DATETIME,'1900')) --DATETIME2()
--        SomeDateTime = CONVERT(DATE,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%DATEDIFF(dd,'1900','2100'))+CONVERT(DATETIME,'1900')) --DATE
   INTO #MyHead
   FROM      sys.all_columns ac1
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns ac2
;
--===== Return the first Monday for the year of each given date (and the original date) as well
     -- as a weekday name and day check for the date created by the formula.  The FirstMondayOfYear
     -- should (obviously) always be a Monday and it should always be a day of 7 or less.
   WITH cteFindMonday AS
(
 SELECT  SomeDateTime
        ,FirstMondayOfYear  = DATEADD(dd,(DATEDIFF(dd,'1753',DATENAME(yy,SomeDateTime))+6)/7*7,'1753')
   FROM #MyHead
)
 SELECT  SomeDateTime
        ,FirstMondayOfYear
        ,DoW     = DATENAME(dw,FirstMondayOfYear)
        ,IsValid =  IIF(    DATENAME(dw,FirstMondayOfYear) = 'Monday'
                        AND DATEPART(dd,FirstMondayOfYear) <= 7 
                    ,1,0)
   FROM cteFindMonday
  ORDER BY SomeDateTime
;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly why are the answers here so elaborated when it is quite simple, really:

```
    // You can try any year
    DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2021
    // First you get the first day of the year
    DECLARE @FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR DATE = CAST(@YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-01-01'
    // Then you get its weekday
    DECLARE @FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR_WEEKDAY INT = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR)
    // Then it's just a CASE matter, where you must see if the actual first day of the year is itself a monday or a sunday. If it's a monday we just return the first day, if it's a sunday we just add 1, if it's anything else beyond that we just have to substract the weekday from 9 (which is essentialy the second monday of the year). And we add the result to whichever day of the week is our first day of the year and we always get our first monday
    DECLARE @FIRST_MONDAY_OF_YEAR DATE =
    CASE
        WHEN @FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR_WEEKDAY = 2 THEN @FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR
        WHEN @FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR_WEEKDAY = 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR)
        ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 9 - @FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR_WEEKDAY, @FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR)
    END

    SELECT @FIRST_MONDAY_OF_YEAR
```

Comment: Because of the use of the WEEKDAY DatePart, this is another solution that only works if DATEFIRST is set to 7.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
-- for specific date
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '20220909'
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, - (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @date) / 7) + 1, @date - (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date) - 2)) AS DATE);
-- for current date
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, - (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, GETDATE()) / 7) + 1, GETDATE() - (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 2)) AS DATE);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution assumes that DATEFIRST has been set to 7.